# Typescript template literal strings type error

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

A new version of Typescript is allowing to use template litteral strings as types like for example:

```
type Hey = 'Hey';

type HeyThere = `${Hey} There`;
```

And it's working very well in the playground of Typescript with the last version which is 4.1.3.

But when I try using it in my projects, I still get the "Type expected. ts(1110)" error in my syntax.

Even though of course I updated the package to the latest version, I also tried to use it in a new project created from scratch and still didn't work. I'm sure it's a very simple mistake but I can't fix it. Also this is very new feature so I can't find much answers online.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What gives you this error message? Is it some command involving `tsc`, or intellisense in your code editor, or something else?

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: Are you sure you are using version 4.1.3?

Comment: @НикитаИванов The error messages comes from intellisense yes. I tried on two different computer and projects, still the same issue.

Comment: @slideshowp2 It is the full error message, coming from vscode intellisense.

Comment: @ABOS yes I am sure, I also installed typescript from scratch on other new projects to test, and it's doing the same

Comment: what does `tsc -v` give?

Comment: @ABOS Version 4.1.3

Comment: I made a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-pwdl0?file=/index.ts, and TS can infer type correctly there. Can you use the same config locally and see if it works?

Comment: @ABOS when using  'tsc index.ts', its working correctly, but I still have Intellisense showing me that it's a problem... very annoying. Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: @ABOS Looks like its now working after updating my VS Code... I should have thought about it earlier... But thanks for your help really!

Comment: good to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

update `ts-loader` to version 8 or 9